# Using Jetty as a web container to allow multiple instances to run under same port

Tags: servlets, asynchronous, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

Current Model: One jar file has a Jetty Server embedded which runs on 1 port. I use continuations to suspend HTTP threads and do some actions on timeout. 
Jetty Version: 9.2.14

Objective Model: Multiple Instances of Jar must run on the same port (Different Context). For this, I am planning to use jetty as webcontainer. I need to be internally able to still use continuations for suspending Requests. But since Jetty server starting the jars is not inside the jar, can i still use continuations?

I think i am going fundamentally wrong but not able to grasp it. I am open to upgrade Jetty. I read about Jetty 9.3 having inherent suspend ability in each IO requests. But i did not find ample material in the documentation to understand. Can someone help either with an answer or point me to the right direction?

Comment: I don't think there's anything stopping you from using continuations if you're using jetty as a container rather than embedded. You could also just use asynchronous servlets.

Comment: I had written one test app for the use case and continuation was not working. I assumed Continuation Support API gets configured internally once we start a Jetty Server and since I was starting the Jetty Server outside , continuation won't work. You meant these two (ContinuationSupport and jetty Server) don't have any dependency in terms of configuring each other, right?

Comment: What happened when you called ContinuationSupport.getContinuation?